# Find the latest record

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access I have the DateList table, which holds the due date of different orders. Thus, the table has two columns: OrderNo and DueDate. For some order numbers, there could be multiple DueDates. The table could look like below:

```
OrderNo DueDate
100     12/9/2021
101     20/9/2021
102     30/9/2021
100     7/10/2021
102     11/10/2021
103     15/10/2021
…
```

My goal is write a query to fetch the latest DueDate of each OrderNr.

I created two queries;
the first one, **qry1**, to generate a list of OrdNo without duplications:

```
SELECT  
DateList.OrderNo AS UniqOrderNo 
FROM DateList 
GROUPBY DateList.OrderNo;
```

in the second query, **qry2**, I used the DMax function in order to search through DueDates of each order for the maximum value.

```
SELECT 
qry1.UniqOrderNo
,DMax("[DueDate]","[DateList]","[OrderNo]='[qry1]![UniqOrderNo]'") AS LatDuDate
FROM qry1 
INNER JOIN DateList 
ON qry1.UniqOrderNo = DateList.OrderNo;
```

LatDuDate represents the latest DueDate of the Order.

The query is unfortunately does not work and returns nothing.

Now my questions:

Is there something wrong with my approach / queries?

Is there better way to accomplish this task in MS Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost figured it out yourself. Max returns you the biggest value of the group.

```
SELECT Max(DueDate) DueDate, OrderNo
FROM DateList
GROUP BY OrderNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Christian's answer, but since `OrderNo` is a unique id, you can simply select the `First()` instead of grouping - it performs better. **

Of course it depends on the number of records the table holds.

```
SELECT First(OrderNo) AS OrderNo, Max(DueDate) AS DueDate
FROM DateList;
```

** Source: [Allen Browne - Optimizing queries](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html)

Comment: First() is a very unreliable function in general use. In this scenario is works as expected, but not always.
Whilst generally I wouldn't dare to question Allen Browne's advice - I think you'll find the current version of the Access database engine deals with a grouped query much more efficiently than it did 15-20 years ago.